# discord.py auto delete link has no response

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am making a bot where if you send anything that has `.com` in it, it will delete that message and send a message saying "your message contained a link", but the bot is not working. I have tried a lot of different ways but still cannot get it to work!

```
#--- blacklisted words --- 
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  links = [
    ".com"
  ]
  if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in links):
    await message.delete()
    await message.channel.send("Your message contained a blacklisted word!")
```

I've made sure the bot had perms, checked spellings and everything else I could think of.

Comment: When running the code, if you print a message and send a message does it contain the message you sent?

Comment: do you know if your bot is really receiving the messages? add a line to print the message argument and send a message in the discord to make sure

Comment: Are you sure that this event is before the `bot.run()`? Can't see the whole code so. It should work, it works on mine and the only way I could think to replicate this was putting it after `bot.run()`, maybe you mistakenly put it there?

Comment: Hey @Galaxy_Shot, can you please show us the full code please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
intents = discord.Intents(message_content=True)
```

kwarg to your bot.

for example

```
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

make sure you have enabled the message intent on developer panel

Try testing your command by adding print

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  links = [
    ".com"
  ]
  if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in links):
    print('filter matched for message')
    await message.delete()
    print('deleted message')
    await message.channel.send("your emssage contained a blacklisted word!")
    print('sent response')
```

check what went wrong

This is the solution if you are using discord.py V2.
The code you have provided is very less for reproducing the issue